# Restrict Content Document access

Tags: lightning-experience, permissions, contentdocument

Can I set No Access to Content Documents at the Profile level?

I am working in LEX, with the understanding that there is no way to hide the Upload Files button without customization.  So, I thought I could just restrict access through the object on the profile but Content Document does not appear to be like a normal standard object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can restrict access using the "Files" object in Lightning.

Comment: This might work as well as it seems I can hide the Files tab, so could create permission set for users that should have access to it.

Comment: The Files (there are two of them) object available to me at the Profile level (that allows me to hide the Files tab) is not available to me at the Perm Set level.  Shoot

Answer (score 0):

You can control access to files by *disabling* the **chatter** for the profile. You can use what is called as **Profile-Based Rollout of Chatter**

(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_pbr_prepare.htm&type=5)

If **Profile-Based Chatter Roll-out** is *activated*, and the User Profile has the '**Enable Chatter**' permission disabled, then that *User will not be able to see the 'Files' tab*.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328673&type=1&mode=1